# Material not exporting/importing

Tags: texturing, materials, import

I am doing a project in which I designed a simple environment in Unity (four rooms with furniture). I exported it to Blender in an fbx format.
It seems to have exported fine, expect that I can't see the materials or textures. [image] As you can see from the picture, there is a material assigned to the floor but it is still pink.
I also do not understand why some objects, like the walls of the table showed in the picture are not pink as the setting are the same.

I am completely new to both Unity and Blender and the goal is to ultimately export the environment to OGRE.
I have been reading many forums and tried many different things but so far no luck! It might be a simple fix but I do not know where to start looking.

Any help would be appreciated it! Thank you:)